# How do I get rid of the whitespace in my navbar?

Tags: html, css, removing-whitespace

I can't figure out where the whitespace (highlighted with yellow), right from the user icon, is coming from. I want the user button to only have a small margin on its right.

[image]

If I try to inspect it (see image bellow) it says it's part of the *ul* element but I can't find the issue.

[image]

I don't know what snippet to share because I'm not sure where the problem is but bellow is the CSS of the *ul* element, the entire CSS and the HTML where the *ul* element is.

The HTML:

https://github.com/NezaVizintin/Swapet/blob/master/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

CSS specifically for the *ul* element:

```
nav > ul { /*all elements together on navbar*/
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: start;
align-items: center;
margin: unset; }
```

This entire CSS:

https://github.com/NezaVizintin/Swapet/blob/master/wwwroot/css/custom-swapet.css

Comment: In the screenshot inspecting the element, the website looks different and the devtools are taking some space, you should probably move the devtools to the bottom to show the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though Your question was not that clear but based upon my understanding I can give you these solutions.

In the second Image the green portion is the `left-padding` for the `<ul>` tag you can remove it by just setting the `padding-right:0`.

Talking about why there is the **yellow marked space to the right of your user ?** , it is because you have set the `justify-content` to `start` - which forces your `<ui>` element to strictly align towards the left of the container leaving that yellow space to the right.

A **possible solution** to this can be setting the `justify-content` to `space-between`-which will let all of the `li` to be equally spaced and also makes your user align to the right removing that yellow space and then you can add a little margin to the right if you want.

**Proposed Changes to CSS**

```
nav > ul {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-between; /*proposed changes*/
align-items: center;
margin: unset;
padding:0;                      /*proposed changes*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you both! Setting padding to 0 still didn't work but that led me to remember the unset option, which worked great.

Answer (score 1):

Here,
I don't know the exact problem but and `padding: 0` will solve your problem.

```
nav > ul { /*all elements together on navbar*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: start;
    align-items: center;
    margin: unset;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Let me know if it does not works for you.